# Oracle Query to Select minimum and maximum date of each day by employee

Tags: sql, oracle

My DB record and TIME_IO is time Stamp field of oracle db.

[image]

I need a query to select record in this format, the query should return minimum and maximum TIME_IO for each day and for each employee.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this

```
select TRUNC(timeio) as day_timeio, min(timeio) as min_timeoi, 
        max(timeio) as max_timeoi 
 from table
        group by TRUNC(timeio)
```

Comment: ... you probably need to select (and group by) userid as well ?

Comment: Yes. Looks like OP edited the question after my answer